Adding multiple positions at same company to resume class document
I'm using the resume.cls made by Trey Hunner (see here for Github link if interested). The below is a minimally-reproducible example.
The resume.cls only allows me to add in a single job title and year(s) employed for a given company. In practice, it is common for people to have multiple jobs at the same company with different dates. I want to edit the cls file to permit this.
This is the essential part of the class file that allows you to repro the document:
%-----------------------------------
%   SET UP CLASS/DOC
%-----------------------------------
\ProvidesClass{resume}[2010/07/10 v0.9 Resume class]

\LoadClass[11pt,letterpaper]{article} % Font size and paper type

\usepackage[parfill]{parskip} % Remove paragraph indentation
\usepackage{array} % Required for boldface (\bf and \bfseries) tabular columns
\usepackage{ifthen} % Required for ifthenelse statements

\pagestyle{empty} % Suppress page numbers

%-----------------------------------
%   SECTION FORMATTING
%-----------------------------------
% Defines the rSection environment for the large sections within the CV
\newenvironment{rSection}[1]{ % 1 input argument - section name
  \sectionskip
  \MakeUppercase{\bf #1} % Section title
  \sectionlineskip
  \hrule % Horizontal line
  \begin{list}{}{ % List for each individual item in the section
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{1.5em} % Margin within the section
  }
  \item[]
}{
  \end{list}
}

%-----------------------------------
%   WORK EXPERIENCE FORMATTING
%-----------------------------------
\newenvironment{rSubsection}[4]{ % 4 input arguments - company name, year(s) employed, job title and location
 {\bf #1} \hfill {#2} % Bold company name and date on the right
 \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}{}{ % If the third argument is not specified, don't print the job title and location line
  \\
  {\em #3} \hfill {\em #4} % Italic job title and location
  }\smallskip
  \begin{list}{$\cdot$}{\leftmargin=0em} % \cdot used for bullets, no indentation
   \itemsep -0.5em \vspace{-0.5em} % Compress items in list together for aesthetics
  }{
  \end{list}
  \vspace{0.5em} % Some space after the list of bullet points
}

% The below commands define the whitespace after certain things in the document - they can be \smallskip, \medskip or \bigskip
\def\namesize{\huge} % Size of the name at the top of the document
\def\addressskip{\smallskip} % The space between the two address (or phone/email) lines
\def\sectionlineskip{\medskip} % The space above the horizontal line for each section 
\def\nameskip{\bigskip} % The space after your name at the top
\def\sectionskip{\medskip} % The space after the heading section

If you save the above as resume_minimal.cls, and run the following it will produce a PDF with a single company, job title, dates, and location, as well as some itemized descriptions of the job (image attached):
%-------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%-------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[a4paper]{resume_minimal} % Use the custom resume.cls style

\usepackage[left=0.75in,top=0.6in,right=0.75in,bottom=0.6in]{geometry} % Document margins

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

%------------------------------------------------
%   WORK EXPERIENCE SECTION
%------------------------------------------------

\begin{rSection}{Experience}

\begin{rSubsection}{Walmart}{Ohio, USA}{Business Analyst}{October 2019 - May 2024} 

\item Making things great for the business was my goal and I achieved this with gusto.
\item Analysing things is how I achieved my goals, and that's why I got a promotion.

\end{rSubsection}
\end{rSection}

\end{document}


However, let's say i got a promotion in May 2024 and I now want to add a line above 'Business Analyst' that says 'Senior Business Analyst' with new dates (e.g. 'May 2024 - present').
This is what I attempted to allow me to (optionally) include multiple positions for the same company:
\newenvironment{rSubsection}[6]{ % 6 input arguments - company name, location, job title, year(s) employed, job title, year(s) employed, etc.
 {\bf #1} \hfill {#2} % Bold company name and location on the right
 \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}{}{ % If the third argument is not specified, don't print the job title and and year(s) employed
  \\
  {\em #3} \hfill {\em #4} % Italic job title and year(s) employed
  }\smallskip
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{ % If the fifth argument is not specified, don't print the job title and year(s) employed line
  \\
  {\em #5} \hfill {\em #6} % Italic job title and year(s) employed
  }\smallskip
  \begin{list}{$\cdot$}{\leftmargin=0em} % \cdot used for bullets, no indentation
   \itemsep -0.5em \vspace{-0.5em} % Compress items in list together for aesthetics
  }{
  \end{list}
  \vspace{0.5em} % Some space after the list of bullet points
}

I figured i just need new if-then logic for additional titles, but I think i'm operationalising it incorrectly as I don't see the desired result. I tried nesting the second if-then inside the first, but that hasn't worked either.
Can anyone see where i'm going wrong here? I'd be grateful for any ideas. Please let me know if you need more information

Welcome to TeX.SE! This class is very old! Have you looked for a newer one?

Thank you! I haven’t, but it seems that I only need to make a few small changes to the class and it’ll meet my needs. I overall really like this class, have been using it for many years, and have my cv written up in it already. So it doesn’t feel like working with a new class is the optimal way forward for me

Working with Claude, I am 99% of the way there. This is what I ended up with:
%-----------------------------------
%   WORK EXPERIENCE FORMATTING
%-----------------------------------
\newenvironment{rSubsection}[4]{
  {\bf #1} \hfill {#2} % Company name and location
  \begin{list}{}{
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{0em}
    \setlength{\itemsep}{0em}
    \setlength{\parsep}{0em}
  }
    \item[]
    #3 % Job titles and dates (now a parameter that can contain multiple entries)
  \end{list}
  \vspace{-0.5em}
    \begin{list}{$\cdot$}{\leftmargin=0em} % \cdot used for bullets, no indentation
   \itemsep -0.5em \vspace{-0.5em} % Compress items in list together for aesthetics
    #4 % Job descriptions
}{
  \end{list}
}

% Modified jobentry command to allow multiple entries
\newcommand{\jobentry}[1]{
  #1
}

% New command for individual positions
\newcommand{\position}[2]{
  {\em #1} \hfill {#2} \\
}

The above are edits to the WORK EXPERIENCE FORMATTING section of the .cls file. Instead of adding additional \ifthenelse clauses, i've created two new commands \jobentry and \position. These can then be called within item #3 as such:
\begin{rSection}{Experience}

\begin{rSubsection}{Walmart}{Ohio, USA}{
  \jobentry{
    \position{Senior Business Analyst}{May 2024 - Present}
    \position{Business Analyst}{October 2019 - May 2024}
    \position{Junior Business Analyst}{January 2018 - October 2019}
  }
}{
\item Making things great for the business was my goal and I achieved this with gusto.
\item Analysing things is how I achieved my goals, and that's why I got a promotion.
}
\end{rSubsection}

\end{rSection}

Producing a PDF like this:

I'm still not happy with the right-alignment of location as I want it to be aligned with the dates, but i've Claude seems to be in a loop and isn't helping me any more. If anyone knows how to solve this i'd be open to suggestions!
Cheers

Note that on this site you should only post answers as such if they at least can solve the main part of your question. Otherwise, it is better to add your preliminary answer as edit to your original question. (I leave it to you to decide what to do though.)

Hi Jasper, do you not think my answer solves the main part of my question?
